# Angular 2 Animations "Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not supported."

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I've created the following Angular 2 animation:

```
trigger('detailsContentAnimation',
  [
    state('1', style(
      {
        'height': '*',
        'padding-top': '*',
        'padding-bottom': '*'
      })),
    state('0', style(
      {
        'height': 0,
        'padding-top': 0,
        'padding-bottom': 0
      })),
    transition('* => *', animate('400ms ease-out'))
  ])
```

This animation should slide in / out the following HTML content:

```
<div>
 <div class="col-card__content-div">
  <div [@detailsContentAnimation]="areDetailsVisible" class="card-block">
    <ng-content select=".col-card__contentselector--body"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

While the animation is occuring, I get the following error:

> Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not supported."

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: I've tested it and there seems to be a problem with the padding- and margin-Property. Is there another way to collapse the content of the card in the animation?

Comment: Could you post the css styles for `col-card__content-div`, `card-block`, and `col-card__contentselector--body`?

Comment: `card-block` is from bootstrap, `col-card__contentselector--body` currently has no style and `col-card__content-div` has the following style:
`.col-card__content-div {
  overflow: hidden;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the code provided this seems to work for me (tested in Chrome 59.0.3, Firefox 54.0.1, and Safari 9, all on Mac).
See this [minimal example on Github](https://github.com/SpaceFozzy/angular-animated-slidedown) which is [running live here](http://demo2.robotmonster.ca). Here is a direct link to the [card component](https://github.com/SpaceFozzy/angular-animated-slidedown/blob/master/src/app/card/card.component.ts) and [card template](https://github.com/SpaceFozzy/angular-animated-slidedown/blob/master/src/app/card/card.component.html) which use your code. I tried but was unable to reproduce your error.

My versions:

```
"@angular/animations": "^4.3.1",
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0"
```

I suggest trying to:

1. Update your animations library if needed
2. Compare your code to my example to spot the difference
3. Post more code, your project, or a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I can help you debug further :)